# Msg 512... SQL Server code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with my code:

```
drop type Pesel
go 

drop assembly pesel 
go 

create assembly pesel 
authorization dbo from 'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Projekt\Projekt.dll' with permission_set = safe 
go 

create type dbo.Pesel 
external name Pesel.Pesel 
go 

declare @a Pesel 

select * from dbo.dane 

set @a = (select numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane) 
select @a.ValidatePesel() 
select @a.BirthDate() 
select @a.GetGender()
```

I got an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

When I try it for example like this:

```
set @a = cast('93071611479' as pesel)
```

everything is OK, but its still only 1 answer :P

EDIT:

I've managed to solve my problem at least partly but now I want to place my results into table

```
drop type Pesel
go
drop assembly pesel
go
create assembly pesel
authorization dbo
from 'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Projekt\Projekt.dll'
with permission_set = safe
go
create type dbo.Pesel
external name Pesel.Pesel
go
declare @a Pesel
select * from dbo.dane
declare @b int
set @b = 0
while @b < (select max(P_Id) from dane)
begin
set @a = (select numer_pesel as pesel from dane where P_Id = 1+@b) 
set @b += 1
if (select numer_pesel from dane) = null
break
select @a.ValidatePesel()
select @a.BirthDate() 
select @a.GetGender()
end
```

I've tried to create table and place the above selects into columns but somehow it doesn't work. Any hints guys :)?

Comment: (1) I removed the MySQL tag because the code is obviously T-SQL.  (2) The error message is pretty obvious:  `dane` has more than one row.   Is there something you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Gordon's comment:

```
set @a = (select numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane)
```

In the statement above, `select numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane` is returning more than one value. This would be like saying:

`set @a = 123 456 654`

Instead, you can select the TOP 1 just to get your code to run and then figure out what you need to do in your `SELECT` statement to get the actual value you want.

`set @a = (select top 1 numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane)`

You are going to have to limit your sub select, `(select numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane)` with some sort of condition or filter.

Comment: Then again, a `TOP 1` *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` is just returning 1 arbitrary row, in no particular order - usually not exactly what you want .....

Comment: @marc_s i agree, that's why i said it would just get the code to run and then he can figure out how to limit it to get the correct value. Definitely not going to be THE value the OP wants out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the below line:

```
set @a = (select numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane)
```

Run the below query and see if it returns more than a row.

```
select numer_pesel as pesel from dbo.dane
```

If so, add a condition with where statement making the query to return unique numer_pesel